# A problem on eigenvalues of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The imaginary parts of the eigenvalues of the matrix A.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 2 & 5 \\
    2 & -3 & 6 \\
    0 & 0 & -3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
are

(A)$0,0,0$

(B)$1,-1,0$

(C)$2,-2,0$

(D)$3,-3,0$

My input: In this I tried to calculate eigenvalues like we do in normal subtracting $\lambda$ from diagonal entries and solving cubic equation after taking determinant of matrix A. But this question came in $1$ marks . I think there is some fact which is being used here. Please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eigenvalue of $-3$ (which is real) can be read off directly.

Hence it suffices to study the eigenvalue of the upper left $2$ by $2$ matrix. Of which it is **symmetric**, which means the eigenvalue is real.

Edit:

Notice that the standard way of computing eigenvalues of matrix $A$ is to compute the charactheristic polynomial, $\det(A-\lambda I ) = 0$. Now, notice that $A$ is a block-triangular matrix, $A = \begin{bmatrix} B & C \\ 0 & D \end{bmatrix}$.

We have 
\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I)&= \det \begin{pmatrix} B-\lambda I & C \\ 0 & D-\lambda I \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \det(B-\lambda I) \det(D - \lambda I)
\end{align}

here $D$ is $-3$ and hence $\lambda = -3$ is a solution. In fact for this particular example, since $A$ is a $3$ by $3$ matrix and $D$ is a scalar, just perform Laplace expansion along the last row to obtain the result.

Comment: I am a beginner. Please tell me how can one  tell $-3$ is one of the eigenvalue. I could read it if it was an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: When the matrix is a block triangular matrix, we can compute the eigenvalue block by block, hence the number $5$ and $6$ are just there for distraction purpose, they do not change the eigenvalues of the matrix. Hence, I can change those numbers to arbitrary numbers and the eigenvalues remains the same.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with block diagonal matrices. I will learn them now. Thankyou!

Comment: Could you give me any source for Block matrices. I want to read them.

Comment: http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf I actually just learn more stuff as I solve more problems rather than reading systematically. Wikipedia helps.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will surely imply them on my practice problems thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (A).

You don't really have to do any calculation. But first observe that $(0, 0, 1)$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $-3$.

For the other two eigenvalues, all you have to do is observe that the corresponding eigenvectors have the form $a= (a_1, a_2, 0)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, 0)$. This means the eigenvector corresponds to the eigenvector of the upper left symmetric square matrix. Since it's symmetric then the eigenvalues must be real.

Comment: How can we deduce $-3$ is an eigenvalue without following proper method?

Comment: Take $(0, 0, 1)$ and multiple it by the matrix, then you will get $(0, 0, -3) = -3(0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: @user459687 The last row is a multiple of $(0,0,1)$, so it is a *left* eigenvector with eigenvalue $-3$; left and right eigenvalues are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Take the last row to compute the determinant:  $(-3-\lambda)((-3-\lambda) (3-\lambda)-4)=0 \implies (-3-\lambda) =0 \text { or }(-3-\lambda)(3-\lambda) -4=0 \implies  \lambda =-3 \text { or } \lambda ^2-13=0 \implies \lambda =-3 \text { or } \lambda =\pm \sqrt {13}$.

So there are three  *real* eigenvalues...

Therefore the answer is A...